# Set value when null nested objects returned during filtering list using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects PurchaseTripSegments.
I created a filter using Java 8 streams and added methods to test for nulls in all of the nested objects.
Example of method to use Optional

```
private static Optional<Integer> getStopOff(PurchasedCostTripSegment purchasedCostTripSegment) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(purchasedCostTripSegment.getStopOff()) l
        .map(stopOff -> stopOff.getStopOffLocation())
        .map(stopOffLocation -> stopOffLocation.getNumberCode());
    }
```

This is the filter for the list

```
filteredRailList = purchasedTripSegments.stream()
   .filter(segment -> PurchasedVendorType.RAIL.equals(segment.getVendorType()))    
   .filter(distinctByKeys(segment -> Arrays.asList(getBilling(segment), getOriginCode(segment),
                        getDestinationCode(segment), getStopOff(segment))))   
   .filter(segment -> BILLING_METHOD_LOCAL.equals(segment.getBillingMethod()) ||
     (BILLING_METHOD_RULE.equals(segment.getBillingMethod()) &&
        !(getDestinationCode(segment).equals(getStopOff(segment))))) 
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have a test case that has 3 segments in the list and one of the segments has a null Destination object.
The results of the test returns all 3 of the segments.
I would like the segment with a null object to be removed from the list but apply the filter to the other 2 segments. But the null objects are nested. The static method above shows one of the objects has 3 levels.

I found the `orElse()` method.  I tried appending it to my private methods that use Optional but it is throwing an error **incompatible types** expecting Optional Integer but found Integer.

Comment: *I would like the segment with a null object to be removed from the list but apply the filter to the other 2 segments.*, wasn't really clear from the previous question, but if that is the case, you should have a filter to start off with as `.filter(segment -> PurchasedVendorType.RAIL.equals(segment.getVendorType())).filter(segment -> getDestinationCode(segment).isPresent())...`. On the other hand, you might want to store these to local variables before the stream pipeline for reusability.

Comment: Over the *error incompatible types expecting Optional Integer but found Integer.*, the `orElse` API returns a `T` value and not an `Optional<T>` value that you have previously. So using that would require method signature changes.

Comment: Sorry about the inconsistency..I realized that my test case showed that if there is a null value the filtering stops and returns all of the segment.  I would like the other non-null segments to be filtered and ignore/remove the null value segment

Comment: Adding the `isPresent` worked! Your suggestion to _store there to local variables..._. I don't understand. Do you mean save the booleans from the method **getDestinationCode** locally and use the boolean values before calling the filtering method?

Comment: The suggestion to use local variables is to make sure of reusability in code, instead of calling the same method two or more times.